# Dealing with JSON Response in cURL

Tags: php, json, curl, null

I'm dealing with `JSON` Response using `cURL`, However its just return `NULL`. I don't understand where i'm doing wrong ?

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
        $data = array('name' => 'Hagrid','age' => '36');

        $bodyData = array('json' => json_encode($data));
        $bodyStr = http_build_query($bodyData);
        $url = 'http://bulk10.co.in/curl/index.php';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Content-Length: '.strlen($bodyStr)));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bodyStr);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $result;
    ?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    $order_info = json_decode($_POST['json']);
    var_dump($order_info);
?>
```

Can any one help me why i'm getting `NULL` response ?

Comment: Did you get something on `$_POST['json']` (without `json_decode`) ? From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):  _NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit._

Comment: No its just showing empty...

Comment: Sorry but all is right, I just did a test on my localhost. You should have a misconfiguration on your web server or a web cache.

Comment: What did u get as output ?

Comment: `object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'name' => string 'Hagrid' (length=6)
  public 'age' => string '36' (length=2)` on `echo $result;`

Comment: Ohk let me check on new server. Hope this will fix my problem :-)

Comment: Yah ! Its worked :-) This was cause by the server.. I have to change my servers to new hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem with my current server returning `NULL`. One of Stack user checked this code and told he's getting perfect answer. Then I've checked this in different server, Now its working absolutely fine.